# Run Energia from SRAM / Memory (CC3200 Launchpad)

Tags: launchpad, energia

In the code composer Studio it is possible to "flash"/load your program straight into the LaunchPads SRAM memory and run it without touching the flash.

Is there a way to do the same in Energia?

PS: I am familiar with Arduino but not with CCS.

Comment: You mean like programming the board from CCS? Or choosing where the code is to be loaded? Usually a linker file will do that job, of specifying where to put each function/variables and so on.

Comment: For reverse engineering purposes I would like to keep the FLASH as it it is. My Code should be loaded to sram just like in ccs.

Comment: Looking at the GitHub of Energia it seems that it does not write to flash by standard (and most of the times that is what any programmer/IDE is expected to), but if you have some important data on the flash that you want to secure. Wait for someone else to respond or try it out in a different board, as it seems that the standard is to write only to SRAM.

Comment: I was able to backup the flash, so I can try what happens.

Comment: Energia overwrites the flash (/sys/mciimg.bin) which isn't optimal

Comment: If there's is any place you can find out how to not overwrite flash would be in their forum, https://forum.43oh.com/forum/119-energia/ if you do find the solution, please post it here (answer your own question).